# Why is the sub-menu in this accordion menu not staying open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I adapted a menu from CSS MenuMaker, and I've been hunting for why it behaves differently. It is [here](http://moonwards.com/planning.html). When you click on the menu item, the sub-menu opens, but if the mouse remains over the clicked menu item, the rest doesn't move down to make room, and the sub-menu doesn't use the styling it is supposed to. Instead it uses the styling of a top-level menu item.

HTML

```
<div class="col-2 col-m-2 accordian darkYellow roundLeft">
    <p class="title">Melt-in-Place Station (MIP)
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub"><a><span>Reference Docs</span></a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20150000305.pdf">
                    <span>Melted regolith construction</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a><span>Forum Threads</span></a></li>
        <li class="has-sub"><a><span>Models</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordian,
.accordian ul,
.accordian li,
.accordian a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  color: yellow;
}
p.title {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 16px 6px;
}
.accordian a {
  line-height: 1.3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.accordian {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
    text-align: right;
}
.accordian > ul > li {
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}
.accordian > ul > li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}
.accordian > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.6);
}
.accordian > ul > li > a > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
.accordian > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.accordian > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.accordian > ul > li.active > a {
    background: #333;
}
.accordian > ul > li.has-sub > a span {
  background: url(http://www.moonwards.com/img/iconPlus.png) no-repeat left center; 
}
.accordian > ul > li.has-sub.active > a span {
  background: url(http://www.moonwards.com/img/iconMinus.png) no-repeat left center; 
}
/* Sub menu */
.accordian ul ul {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  display: none;
}
.accordian ul ul li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}
.accordian ul ul a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 400italic;
}
```

jQuery

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.accordian > ul > li > a').click(function() {
  $('.accordian li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 
  var checkElement = $(this).next();
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal');
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('.accordian ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
  }
  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;   
  }     
});
});
} )( jQuery );
```

I assume this is some dumb thing, but any help appreciated.

Comment: I copied your code in a fiddle and it seems to work correctly on Chrome here. When the first item is clicked the other two move down to make space. https://jsfiddle.net/Lugpj1wx/

Comment: I missed a squigly bracket. My bad. That's why I deleted my comment. Anyway, I'm with fbid on this one. It seems to work fine. What are we looking for?

Comment: Wait, I just noticed a glitch in the actual website you linked. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: Yeah - so something else is screwing it up, a different css or js doc?

Comment: @kimholder it's problably some other class or something that is being activeted when the hover event is triggered on the `<li class="has-sub">`

Comment: @fbid i've been looking for that but i can't find it... checking...

Comment: @fbid - okay, found it... shoulda checked in codepen, that might have twigged me... thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After inspecting I think I found the culprit. Try edit your CSS like this:

```
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative; /* relative, not absolute */
  top: 100%;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 0, 1);
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: both of our answers resulted in the same exact outcome but two different aproaches. that's a beautiful thing :) Good job by the way

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not entirely CSS. I just figured out that the LI's height is covering the dropdown. However, if you reduce the height of the LI, the next LI doesn't open the amount it needs to. A quick patch would be to apply this CSS below however, I would much rather get the JQuery guys here to help you out.

```
  .accordian ul ul {
    padding: 5px 12px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: relative;
    background: none;
 }
```

p.s. This solves the problem you asked, but you need to tweak the font and size so that there is no difference

Comment: Hm... does the other answer resolve that? It seems to me the css rules i had in the main.css doc were telling the li to do two different things on hover, when it executed both instructions that was the result. The jQuery for the menu adds a class to the li when it is clicked, which also means you are hovering. Removing the conflict solved the problem.